# Android - Mobile Like Button

Tags: android, facebook

5 days ago, on 10/02/2014, Facebook published on their developer blog a new post:
"Mobile Like Button now Available to Everyone": https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2014/10/02/mobilelike/
and has provided documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/like-button

I have tried to follow the documentation to have users like my App but have had no success:

- the Like button does not show the number of Likes the app already has
- when I press the Like button, a white screen pops up with a grey Facebook Logo in the middle and a cancel link at the bottom.
  Has anybody successfully implemented that new button?

Here is what I did following the Facebook documentation:

- I created a Page on Facebook for my App an got its pageId, the code at the end of the page url:
  https://www.facebook.com/pages/[myPage]/[myPageId]
- I added my app in my Facebook developer account and got an ApplicationId: [myAppId]
- I installed the Facebook SDK and added it to my Android project

Then, in the main Activity of my app:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
    LikeView likeView = (LikeView) findViewById(R.id.like_view);
    likeView.setObjectId("[myPageId]");
...

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, null);
...
```

In res/values/strings.xml, I added:

```
<string name="facebook_app_id">[MyAppId]</string>
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file, I added in the Application tab:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

Comment: A few questions: do you have the facebook app installed? and if not, how long did you wait on the pop up dialog screen? Is your app public? and if not, are you testing with a user who's a admin/developer/tester on the app? Did you set the right key hash in your app settings?

Comment: I created a test app in the Facebook developers site. Yes, I am testing with my personal FB account. The account has been registered as the Admin of the app in the app Facebook developers page. Yes, the right key hash has been set, the ones for my dev environment. I can see in Facebook developers "Apps event": I logged in and sent  a couple of "fb_dialogs_present_like" events.

Comment: I am getting a "Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider" in LogCat. I have checked the following: I do have an internet connection, I have the internet permission in the manifest, I have checked again my hashkey and my app id.

Comment: I have tried the Facebook alternate method "if you don't want to use the UiLifecycleHelper, call sdkInitialize" and I am getting the same error.

Comment: If I try to run my app on an emulator (Genymotion Glaxy S5 running Android 4.4.2) that does not have the Facebook App it works just fine: clicking the button redirects me to a web Facebook Login page, after login in, the FB page of my app is shown and liked. When I go back to my app, the "Like" button has changed and I can see the number of likes my page has got. BUT, if I uninstall the Facebook app from my device(Nexus 7 2012 running Android 4.4.4), this does not work, I am not getting the Login screen.

Comment: The "Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider" is innocuous, and is unrelated to this issue. It's weird that the web dialog is working for you on the emulator but not on a device. Couple more questions: Are you using the same keystore for your emulator and device builds? Do you have anything special set up on your device (like certificates, etc)?

Comment: Can you also try to see if anything from the WebDialog class works for you (like the FeedDialog)?

Comment: Yes, exact same code and keystore for emulator and device. No, I do not have anything special on my device. I will try the WebDialog class.

Comment: To try to isolate things, I created a new app from scratch. I have some FB code including a FeedDialog. Everything works fine on my Nexus 7. If I know add the Like Button, I have the same behavior as what I described before. I ran this app on 2 Genymobile emulators with no FB app installed, one running 4.4.2 and the other one running 4.2.2. Both worked fine. I installed it on a Moto G running  Android 4.4.4 and it works fine. Something has to be wrong on my Nexus, but what can it be?

Comment: same weired issue when i hit like button it is throwing this exception. "Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.wakizashi.provider.PlatformProvider" anyone please help me to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you MUST NOT set a numeric height to the faceboo LikeView, it has to be wrap content.

Answer (score 0):

When everything confirmed to be correct.Then don't forget to add your facebook account as a tester of your app, so that you can test the whole function.Also, if you want to use "like button" with anyone else, you should submit your app to Facebook and ask for "like button" this ability at [Here](http://developers.facebook.com)